# Show that the set of functions under composition is isomorphic to $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, function-and-relation-composition

Show that the set $\{f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5, f_6\}$ of functions $\mathbb{R}-\{0, 1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}-\{0,1\}$ under composition is isomorphic to $S_3$, where $$f_1(x)= x\\ f_2(x) = 1-x\\f_3(x)=1/x\\f_4(x)=1-1/x\\f_5(x)=1/(1-x)\\f_6(x)=x/(x-1)$$

I am unsure how to start with this. I want to understand how to go about doing this and not just the answer. Any pointers would be a appreciated.

Comment: One way to go about it is to look how the functions behave on a set of three points $S = \{A,\, B,\, C\}$ which they all leave invariant (that means $f_i(S) = S$ for all $i$). I would suggest looking at $A = 0,\, B = 1,\, C = \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You need to construct a bijection between your $6$ functions and the $3!=6$ elements of $S_3$. Try writing them down in separate columns and matching them together. Can you spot the identity element? Compose each function with itself until you get the identity function; this will help you figure out its order.

Once you've done that, you should find that $3$ functions have order $2$. Arbitrarily assign these $3$ functions to the three $2$-cycles in $S_3$. To figure out how to assign the remaining $2$ functions of order $3$, pick any two distinct $2$-cycles in $S_3$ and multiply them to obtain a $3$-cycle. Match this $3$-cycle to the function of order $3$ obtained by composing the corresponding functions of order $2$.

Comment: If $S_3=\{123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321\}$, is a correct bijection to correspond $f_n$ to the nth index of $S_3$? Also, what is the correct notation for this.

Comment: @MuadDib42 Looks good! I would perhaps not write it as a set (since order matters), but instead as a vector or ordered tuple. For example, define the bijection $g:\{f_1,...,f_6\} \to S_3$ by $g(f_n)=k_n$, where:
$$
(k_n)_{n=1}^6 = ((1)(2)(3),(2,3),(1,2),(1,3,2),(1,2,3),(1,3))
$$
Don't worry about how I wrote my cycles. I'm just used to different notation; yours I'm sure is equivalent.

Comment: @Adriano asking for knowledge sake, that your notation translates to earlier notation of yousofsoliman: $(1)(2)(3) = 123, (2,3)=132, (1,2)=213, (1,3,2)= 231, (1,2,3)=312, (1,3)=321$. Your notation lists the exchanged ones in adjacent positions; while the earlier lists by final position.