# Is the group isomorphic to $S_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

$D:= \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0,1\}$
$f(x)= \frac{1}{x} ,g(x)=\frac{x-1}{x} $

To show that the group $G$ generated by those two functions (with $\circ $) is isomorphic to the group $S_3$

I found out that the group is $G=\{x, \frac{1}{x}, \frac{x-1}{x},\frac{1}{1-x}, \frac{x}{x-1}, 1-x\}$
(it has $6$ elements)

I need to show that with linking Panels. Should look like linking panel of $S_3$.

But I can't find the right order of $G$.
Hope someone can help :)

Comment: What is a linking Panel?

Comment: Older posts about the same group:
[Show that the set of functions under composition is isomorphic to $S_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434912) and
[Isomorphisms between group of functions and $S_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668122).

Comment: Is *linking panel* perhaps an incorrect translation of [Cayley table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group has one element of order $1$ ($x$), three elements of order $2$ ($\frac1x$, $1-x$, and $\frac x{x-1}$) and two elements of order $3$ ($\frac{x-1}x$ and $\frac1{1-x}$). Now, simply compute the composition of any two elements of $G$ and you will get basically the same table that you get with the group $S_3$.

Comment: Since $S_3$ is the only non-Abelian group if order $6$, will it be sufficient to show $G$ is non-Abelian?

Comment: @SahibaArora Of course it is. But I think that for someon who is just starting to learn group theory it is a better exercise to find an explicit isomorphism between $G$ and $S_3$.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was just curious.