# Show set of functions forms a group: $x, x+1, x+2, 2x, 2x+1, 2x+2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

Prove that the set of transformations forms a group with order six, under function composition.

> $f_1(x) = x$,
> $f_2(x) = x+1$,
> $f_3(x) = x+2$,
> $f_4(x) = 2x$,
> $f_5(x) = 2x+1$,
> $f_6(x) = 2x+2$

Function composition is finding all possibilities of $f_n(f_m(x))$, and then testing for the group properties.

But, being function, the composition is to be associative. But, am not clear on this part.
Say, taking up a few examples:

1. $$f_6(f_5(f_3(x)))= f_6(2(x+2)+1)=f_6(2x+5)=2(2x+5)+2= 4x+12.$$ $$(f_6(f_5(x))f_3(x)= (2(2x+1)+2)f_3(x)= (4x+4)f_3(x)=(4(x+2)+4)= 4x+12.$$
2. $$f_5(f_3(f_2(x)))= f_5(x+3)= 2(x+3)+1= 2x+7.$$ $$(f_5(f_3(x))f_2(x)= (2(x+2)+1)f_3(x)= (2x+5)f_3(x) = 2(x+2)+5= 2x+9.$$

Q.1. Here, associative property is not seen?

The table is drawn below with $n$ being row, column being $m$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   & x & x+1 & x+2 & 2x & 2x+1 & 2x+2 \\ \hline
x & x & x+1& x+2& 2x & 2x+1& 2x+2\\ \hline 
x+1 & x+1& x+2& x+3& 2x+1& 2x+2 & 2x+3\\ \hline
x+2 & x+2& x+3& x+4& 2x+2& 2x+3& 2x+4\\ \hline
2x & 2x& 2x+1&  2x+2& 4x& 4x+1& 4x+2\\ \hline
2x+1 & 2x+1& 2x+3&  2x+5& 4x+1& 4x+3 & 4x+5\\ \hline
2x+2 & 2x+2& 2x+4&  2x+6& 4x+2& 4x+4 & 4x+6\\ \hline
\end{array}

But, if take with $n$ being column, row being $m$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   & x & x+1 & x+2 & 2x & 2x+1 & 2x+2 \\ \hline
x & x & x+1& x+2& 2x & 2x+1& 2x+2\\ \hline 
x+1 & x+1& x+2& x+3& 2x+2& 2x+3 & 2x+4\\ \hline
x+2 & x+2& x+3& x+4& 2x+4& 2x+5& 2x+6\\ \hline
2x & 2x& 2x+1& 2x+2& 4x& 4x+1& 4x+2\\ \hline
2x+1 & 2x+1& 2x+2& 2x+3& 4x+2& 4x+3 & 4x+4\\ \hline
2x+2 & 2x+2& 2x+3& 2x+4& 4x+4& 4x+5 & 4x+6\\ \hline
\end{array}

Q.2. Are the two approaches equivalent, or not?

[Book page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsEHW.jpg)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135786/discussion-on-question-by-jiten-show-set-of-functions-forms-a-group-x-x1-x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a confusion. Either it is missing that the composition is up to modulo $3$, or the set of functions has been swapped:

The standard exercise consists of the following functions $f_i\colon \mathbb{R}-\{0, 1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}-\{0,1\}$, $i=1,\ldots ,6$  forming a group under composition
$$f_1(x)= x\\ f_2(x) = 1-x\\f_3(x)=1/x\\f_4(x)=1-(1/x)\\f_5(x)=1/(1-x)\\f_6(x)=x/(x-1)$$
The group is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Reference:

[Show that the set of functions under composition is isomorphic to $S_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434912/show-that-the-set-of-functions-under-composition-is-isomorphic-to-s-3?rq=1)

Edit: The inserted image shows that the standard exercise is indeed contained as exercise $4$, and that $5$ is indeed misstated (forgetting modulo $3$).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: I tried to find the comfusion. And indeed, the book the OP is using has also these functions as an exercise.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1782456)

Comment: Does adding the condition of modulo $3$ make these six functions? I mean earlier they are not, else composition would have been associative. But, cannot see how non-functions become functions, by addition of condition.

Comment: @jiten No, these functions are your Exercise $4$. You have asked about Exercise $5$, but there modulo $3$ could help - check it. Then $4x=x$, see Shaun's answer.

Comment: @JoseAvilez It *does* answer the question. Indeed, both sets of functions are exercises in this book, but they haven't been interchanged (first possible answer), but just Exercise $4$ is indeed incomplete in the book (second answer = correct answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a group. It is not closed, since

$$\begin{align}
(f_4\circ f_4)(x)&=f_4(f_4(x))\\
&=2(2x)\\
&=4x,
\end{align}$$

which is not $f_i$ for any $i$, any $x\neq 0$.

Comment: What if the composition is $f\circ g\bmod 3$? Obviously the OP has forgotten or confused something.

Comment: That is something for the OP to make clear. My answer addresses the question as asked. If something else was intended, then @jiten needs to start a new post.

Comment: Have attached page image of Indian author book.