# Isomorphisms between group of functions and $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that the functions $f = \frac{1}{x}$, $g=\frac{x-1}x$ generate a group of functions, the law of composition being the composition of functions, that is isomorphic to the the symmetric group $S_3$. (Source: Artin)

It's pretty easy to find the group of functions, but how do I prove that there is a homomorphism between the two groups?

Comment: Exhibit it. ${}$

Comment: You can start by identifying their (i.e. $f$ and $g$'s) order, and then try mapping them to permutations of that order in $S_3$.

Comment: You are looking for an *isomorphism*. ;) There is always a homomorphism between any two groups (which one?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not hard to see that $g\circ g\circ g(x)=x$ and $f\circ f(x)=x$. Assume that $G=\langle f,g\rangle$. So you can define $\phi:G \rightarrow S_3$:

$$\phi(f)=(1\,2),$$

$$\phi(g)=(1\,2\,3)$$

It is easy to see that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @anon thanks, i always forget \circ. This time, I write it on my hand.